# Can I place a Western Digital RE3 WD1002FBYS in a MacPro1,1?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, mac-pro

I have a bare WD1002FBYS and am wondering if I can place this into a MacPro1,1 (the first Desktop MacPro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like any other 3.5" SATA harddrive, provided you have a spare bay to populate.